# COPY INTO statement is not generating file type as .csv - Snowflake, S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am copying data from Snowflake to S3 using COPY INTO statement.

This is the code:

```
copy into 's3://dev'
  from "TEST_DATABASE"."RAW_DATA"."TEMP_TABLE"
  credentials = (aws_key_id='***' aws_secret_key='***')
  OVERWRITE = TRUE
  file_format = (type=csv compression='none')
  single=true
  max_file_size=4900000000;
```

Data gets copied but I don't get a `.csv` extension.

I get `data` as the filename, not `data.csv`.

What am I doing wrong here?
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: `all I get is data name of file.` - what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, yes that sounds unclear, so I get `data` instead of `data.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a parameter called FILE_EXTENSION within the file format options. This should help you get the desired file extension added. You need to specify this parameter, because you are unloading your data into multiple files, not one single file.

Docs for FILE_EXTENSION: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#type-csv

Comment: I am getting this error: SQL compilation error: invalid parameter 'FILE_EXTENSION'.

Comment: Where did you add it? It has to be inside the file_format-part.

Comment: No I added it outside :/ so my file format should look something like this `file_format = (type=csv compression='none' file_extension= 'csv')?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I added it in file_format and it works. Maybe you can provide code for others to have

Answer (score 0):

For a single file, you just specify the full file name including the extension:

```
copy into 's3://dev/MyFileName.csv'
  from "TEST_DATABASE"."RAW_DATA"."TEMP_TABLE"
  credentials = (aws_key_id='***' aws_secret_key='***')
  OVERWRITE = TRUE
  file_format = (type=csv compression='none')
  single=true
  max_file_size=4900000000;
```

If you don't specify the `single=true` option, you need to specify the FILE_EXTENSION option:

```
copy into 's3://dev'
  from "TEST_DATABASE"."RAW_DATA"."TEMP_TABLE"
  credentials = (aws_key_id='***' aws_secret_key='***')
  OVERWRITE = TRUE
  file_format = (type=csv compression='none')
  FILE_EXTENSION = 'csv'
  max_file_size=4900000000;
```

Comment: I have tried, but I am getting this error: `SQL compilation error: invalid parameter 'FILE_EXTENSION'`

Comment: Scroll down to the note on FILE_EXTENSION. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#format-type-options-formattypeoptions. There's a note about using it with the `SINGLE` option. You can use one or the other.

Comment: If possible could you please show the code which is giving you the error, may be the FILE_EXTENSION parameter is not specified at the correct place or is it some other parameter, you can remove that paramter and see if you still get the error.